# Why I am getting the ASCII value of T instead of the T letter

Tags: go

I have this below code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
     book := "The_colour_of_magic"
     fmt.Println(book[0])
}
```

When I am executing this code, I am getting the result as 84 (ASCII value of T alphabet).

May I know why I am getting the answer as 84 instead of T.

Comment: fmt.Println does a lot of magic. book[0] is a byte is a uint8 and thus printed as a decimal number. If you want the byte 84 printed in ASCII use fmt.Printf with the %c verb.

Comment: Remember, book[0] may not even represent a whole character. To be Unicode-compliant, you should convert the string into `[]rune`, which is in turn an array of characters, instead of bytes.

Answer (score 4):

By definition string is a slice of bytes and byte is nothing but unsigned int 8 (uint8)

When you are referring to book[0] you are referring a byte and it uint8.

try adding this line to see type of book[0]

```
fmt.printf("Type of book[0]:%T", book[0])
```

As you are attempting to print value in book[0], it will print Unisgned Integer value in the byte.

Comment: Thanks Sadanand for clearing this confusion.